# What's the point of JAAS

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jaas

What's the point of JAAS if I have to write my own {whatever}LoginModule and everything else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JAAS provides an abstraction layer between your application and the underlying authentication mechanism. Therefore, you could change the authentication mechanism used by your application without having to change any of your application code.

Answer (score 6):

Well that is the beauty of it really..

We used JAAS in a big mortgage application system, and while we used a LoginModule based on properties, the big mortage bank used an own implemented LoginModule based on active directory, without we ever having to change something in code.

Answer (score 3):

Just like with any other standard you get portability, plugability, and extensibility for free (or almost for free).

Comment: Dont forget the millions of stack traces you get along with it.